# Updating Play Store listing with new Reverse-DNS naming convention

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app listed on the Play Store with the name `com.foo.bar` but I want to change the URL of the app in the play store to `com.foo.baz`. Will uploading an APK with the new package name as an update automatically change the URL, or will I have to create a new app listing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upload an app with a new package name, you will have to create a new listing. This will cause you to lose any existing download counts, reviews etc. Two things *must* remain constant throughout the life of your app:

- The package name
- The signing key